# Pandas Groupby Frequently Every 5 seconds based on Zones

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a csv file with a user and a timestamp where the user has been in a particular zone. I am trying to use pandas groupby functionality to get common zones that a user has been every five seconds.

```
    user    timestamp                   zones
0   bob     2019-07-17 11:46:46.100     ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]
1   bob     2019-07-17 11:47:04.881     ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]
2   bob     2019-07-17 11:47:09.139     ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]
3   bob     2019-07-17 11:47:13.033     ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]
4   bob     2019-07-17 11:47:16.898     ["Zone 1"]
5   bob     2019-07-17 11:47:20.876     ["Zone 3", "Zone 4"]
6   bob     2019-07-17 11:47:23.869     ["Zone 3", "Zone 4"]
7   bob     2019-07-17 11:48:10.773     ["Zone 3", "Zone 4"]
8   bob     2019-07-17 11:48:58.174     ["Zone 3", "Zone 4"]
9   bob     2019-07-17 11:49:05.159     ["Zone 3", "Zone 4"]
```

I have already tried converting the unix timestamp to datetime.
I used the grouper function to group timestamp every 5 seconds. Here are the results I got, it's not looking very accurate at a glance. The minute 48 is missing and I don't know why there are two "bob" in row 9.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("filtering test.csv")

df.columns = ["user", "timestamp", "zones"]
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')
df.groupby([df['zones'],pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='5s')]).sum().reset_index()
```

```
                   zones    timestamp           user
0   ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]    2019-07-17 11:46:45     bob
1   ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]    2019-07-17 11:47:00     bob
2   ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]    2019-07-17 11:47:05     bob
3   ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]    2019-07-17 11:47:10     bob
4   ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]    2019-07-17 11:49:50     bob
5   ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]    2019-07-17 11:49:55     bob
6   ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]    2019-07-17 11:50:00     bob
7   ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]    2019-07-17 11:50:05     bob
8   ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]    2019-07-17 11:51:15     bob
9   ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]    2019-07-17 11:51:20     bobbob
```

I expect the output to look similar to this:

```
                       zones    timestamp           user
0   ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]    2019-07-17 11:46:45     bob
1   ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]    2019-07-17 11:47:00     bob
2   ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]    2019-07-17 11:47:05     bob
3   ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]    2019-07-17 11:47:10     bob
4   ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]    2019-07-17 11:47:15     bob
5   ["Zone 1"]              2019-07-17 11:47:20     bob
6   ["Zone 3", "Zone 4"]    2019-07-17 11:47:25     bob
7   ["Zone 3", "Zone 4"]    2019-07-17 11:48:05     bob
8   ["Zone 3", "Zone 4"]    2019-07-17 11:48:55     bob
9   ["Zone 3", "Zone 4"]    2019-07-17 11:48:60     bob
```

Answer (score 0):

After grouping by `zones` and `timestamp` you are left only with the `user` column. Applying `sum()` on this will concatenate the `bob`s as many times as you have in a 5s interval. From what I understand you really want to group by `user` and then by `timestamp` like this:
`by_time = df.groupby([df['user'],pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='5s')]).sum()`
This will give you:

```
                                       zones
user          timestamp 
bob 2019-07-17 11:46:45 ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]
    2019-07-17 11:47:00 ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]
    2019-07-17 11:47:05 ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]
    2019-07-17 11:47:10 ["Zone 1", "Zone 2"]
    2019-07-17 11:47:15 ["Zone 1"]
    2019-07-17 11:47:20 ["Zone 3", "Zone 4"]["Zone 3", "Zone 4"]
    2019-07-17 11:48:10 ["Zone 3", "Zone 4"]
    2019-07-17 11:48:55 ["Zone 3", "Zone 4"]
    2019-07-17 11:49:05 ["Zone 3", "Zone 4"]
```

At this point you probably want to get a unique list of the zones on each line. For example:
`by_time['zones'] = by_time['zones'].apply(lambda zone_set_list: list({zone for zone_set in  re.findall(r'\[.*?\]', zone_set_list) for zone in json.loads(zone_set)}))`

```
                                   zones
user          timestamp 
bob 2019-07-17 11:46:45 [Zone 2, Zone 1]
    2019-07-17 11:47:00 [Zone 2, Zone 1]
    2019-07-17 11:47:05 [Zone 2, Zone 1]
    2019-07-17 11:47:10 [Zone 2, Zone 1]
    2019-07-17 11:47:15 [Zone 1]
    2019-07-17 11:47:20 [Zone 3, Zone 4]
    2019-07-17 11:48:10 [Zone 3, Zone 4]
    2019-07-17 11:48:55 [Zone 3, Zone 4]
    2019-07-17 11:49:05 [Zone 3, Zone 4]
```

The reason you don't see `11:48:00` if because you don't have any data in this interval.